# OpenidConnect with IIS application

Tags: c#, openid, openid-connect

I am trying to use owin.openidconnect with idp server, everything works fine on local, but when deployed to iis server,I cannot see the **MessageReceived** event firing in notifications for OpenIdConnect. When I challenge for owin the page redirected IDP page and after signing in there coming back to application but it stays not authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answere after couple of days breaking my head around different forums.. The issue is when I set the redirect-uri for the client id on IDP server, I did not put the "/" at the end of URL. 
But the AuthenticateCoreAsync at the OWIN compoenent has a following check

**if (Options.CallbackPath.HasValue && Options.CallbackPath != (Request.PathBase + Request.Path))
                return null;**

My application url like **http:///** and **CallbackPath** was **/appName** and **Request.PathBase + Request.Path** was like **'/appName' + '/'**. So no match and failed to authenticate.

So here I had two options, quick one was setting the callback URL as below

Option1
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationType = "OpenIdConnect",
                    Authority = OIDC_baseUrl,
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    ClientSecret = clientSecret,
                    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    ResponseType = "code id_token",
                    Scope = "openid",
                    **CallbackPath = '/appName/',**
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = async (context) =>
                        {
                            await GetAccessTokenAndStoreWithIdentity(context);
                        }
                    }
                }

Option 2 : Change the redirect uri on IDP server with "/" at the end.